# How to parse all public method names and method calls inside a method body of a C# class?

Tags: c#, parsing, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Let us consider the following C# code example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void Evaporate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }

    public string Speak()
    {
        string str = "test";
        return string.Format("Hello! My name is {0}", Name);
    }
}
```

From this source code I want to extract all the method/API call names. Using Roslyn, with help of the following code, I can retrieve the public method names declared inside the class Person.

```
IEnumerable<MethodDeclarationSyntax> methods = tree.Root
    .DescendentNodes()
    .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().ToList();

foreach(var method in methods)
{
    Console.WriteLine(method.Identifier);
}
```

This code response with method names **Evaporate** and **Speak**. Now I want to find out the method names/calls inside the public method, e.g: I want to find out **WriteLine** and **Format** too as a response along with other public method names. I tried to generate Semantic Model with help of Roslyn, but I didn't get what I was expecting (it probably gave me the name of basic method calls). Is there any way to find out the inner method names with **Roslyn**? Any other solutions would also be helpful for me.

Comment: If you want the method declarations inside a method body, then you should probably investigate the _`.Body`_ property of the `DescendantNodes`. This is all in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax?view=roslyn-dotnet)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Thanks for your suggestion. **MethodDeclarationSyntax.Body** replies the method body itself. But I didn't find any way to parse method calls from that method body. I am a noob at Roslyn so I am definitely missing something over here.

Comment: You’re  looking for the invocationexpressionsyntax nodes ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `Body` property returns an instance of type `BlockSyntax`. You can see from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.blocksyntax?view=roslyn-dotnet) that this class exposes a `ChildNodes()` method. So:

```
IEnumerable<MethodDeclarationSyntax> methods = tree.Root
  .DescendentNodes()
  .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().ToList();

foreach(var method in methods)
{
  Console.WriteLine(method.Identifier);
  foreach (var child in method.ChildNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>())
  {
    Console.WriteLine(child.Identifier);
  }
}
```

Comment: You also need descendant nodes.